# jQuery | simple function not working? self invoked function

Tags: jquery

please take a look at this jsfiddle: [click](http://bit.ly/15KEAhI)

```
(function() {
    var variable = {

        body : $('body'),

        bg: function() {
            body.css('background', 'green')
        }

    };
})();
```

the console doesn't give back any error.

an short explanation would be great whats wrong here!

Thanks!

Comment: Hello! Please include your code here!  Sourcing it at external sites could result in the link dying in the future.  Including a link to the fiddle is just fine, but putting your code here is highly desirable.  Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  You define an object, assign it to a local variable inside your function and then don't do anything with it.  You aren't calling any function or returning the object so, nothing happens. You've essentially defined a function that defines some variables, but doesn't do anything with them.  Then, you call that function, but it doesn't do anything other than define some things so to no surprise, nothing happens.

Comment: yes it has no particular use. i am just learning and i am at the very beginning. so i played around and tried stuff

Answer (score 1):

You don't call `bg`.
You can do:

```
(function() {
    var variable = {

        body : $('body'),

        bg: function() {
            this.body.css('background', 'green')
        }

    };
    variable.bg();
})();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/13dvxsnf/1/

Answer (score 1):

Look at: http://jsfiddle.net/g3r01zmr/

```js
(function() {
 var variable = {
  body : $('body'),
  bg: function() {
   this.body.css('background', 'green')
  }
 };
    variable.bg()
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You have to call the function, you only have defined it so far. Also you have to use `this` for the `body` variable, because it is not a local variable.